# What algorithms does NSolve use?

Tags: equation-solving, implementation-details

I've been using `NSolve` to find roots, and now I've been wondering what underlying algorithm *Mathematica* uses. It's probably similar to `FindRoot`, so is it the Newton-Raphson method?

In class we've been told that it probably is a mix of the Newton-Raphson and the bisection methods.

Comment: it must be documented somewhere here http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/  specifically here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html  and most probably there http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html

Comment: For sparse linear systems, `Solve` and `NSolve` use several efficient numerical methods, mostly based on Gauss factoring with Markowitz products (approximately 250 pages of code). For systems of algebraic equations, `NSolve` computes a numerical Gröbner basis using an efficient monomial ordering, then uses eigensystem methods to extract numerical roots. See also [Numerical Root Finding](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalRootFinding.html) and [Numerical Equation Solving](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalEquationSolving.html).

Comment: For univariate inputs `NSolve` calls the function `NRoots`. That in turn has a `Method` option. From the documentation for `NRoots`: Possible settings for the Method option include: "Aberth", "CompanionMatrix", and "JenkinsTraub". The methods mentioned in the post are good for finding an individual root (not necessarily of a polynomial) but not really meant for finding all polynomial roots. And bisection is only for real roots.

Answer (score 17):

In at least the univariate case, the guess of "Newton-Raphson" is not too far off. Daniel mentions the three possible methods supported by `NSolve[]`/`NRoots[]` in his comment.

`"CompanionMatrix"` is likely done by forming the [Frobenius companion matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompanionMatrix.html) from the polynomial's coefficients, and then performing the usual QR algorithm to extract the eigenvalues, so that is the odd one out. (There are more efficient structure-exploiting methods than vanilla QR (e.g. [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2009.08.003)), and other possible companion matrices (e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143181)), but it doesn't seem to me that these specializations are exploited.)

The other two are basically specially-adapted Newton-Raphson methods, with somewhat better convergence properties. Jenkins-Traub, which was the default algorithm in older versions of *Mathematica* (I don't know now), can be interpreted as either a Newton-Raphson method applied to a specially constructed rational function, or a modified Rayleigh quotient iteration of the Frobenius companion matrix (making it a direct descendant of the classical [Bernoulli method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68433)). A full description is rather involved, so I'll just link to these [two](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02163334) [papers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0707045).

Aberth's method, on the other hand, is one of a family of "simultaneous iteration" methods that are based on treating the classical [Vieta formulae](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html) as a set of simultaneous nonlinear equations relating the roots and coefficients, and applying Newton-Raphson to that nonlinear system. The classical reference is [this paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2005621). (I demonstrated the derivation of the related but simpler (Weierstrass-)Durand-Kerner iteration in [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/84085).)

A rather comprehensive survey of all these methods is McNamee's [two](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780444527295) [books](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780444527301).

Comment: As for the multivariate case, see [this paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-6303-2_2) by Auzinger and Stetter, and [this paper](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7514) by a certain Mr. Daniel Lichtblau. Gröbner bases are, of course, discussed nicely in [Cox/Little/O'Shea](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-35651-8).