# What algorithm does NSolve use for real solutions of underdetermined systems of polynomial equations?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I am trying to write up a paper with some results form Mathematica (11.2) among other things. I need to know what algorithm does it use when I solve a system of polynomial equations which is underdetermined (infinitely many solutions). In particular, sometimes Mathematica also find real solutions that are embedded into the complex positive-dimensional components. I couldn't find a mentioned of the specific algorithm that Mathematica is using. I believe this code is written by @DanielLichtblau ?
I know this question: [What algorithms does NSolve use?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47112/what-algorithms-does-nsolve-use) 
But this does not mention the specific algorithm for underdetermined polynomial systems and in particular for finding real solutions embedded in complex curves (though Mathematica certainly find these!).

Comment: You could force the various available methods and see which one works / matches the default output.

Comment: @anderstood, there should be some documentation of the methods. I am not looking for proprietary information.

Comment: So you are not looking for the name of the algorithm, but for some *reference* that indicate what algorithm is used? AFAIK the only source of information is the documentation for `NSolve`.

Comment: @anderstood, here is what I find for the implementation details from Mathematica documentation for NSolve: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#25940 This just says that "For systems of algebraic equations, NSolve computes a numerical Gröbner basis using an efficient monomial ordering, then uses eigensystem methods to extract numerical roots." However, these methods are known not to handle real solutions embedded on complex solution-curves. So, this can't be it.