# NSolve Unreliable

Tags: equation-solving

`NSolve` is unpredictably unreliable.  I change a parameter that has no effect on the solution and get one of four outcomes: 1) both correct answers, 2) one correct answer, 3) it just returns the command back, or 4) it hangs for a long time.

```
Do[
  Print[r, " ",
    NSolve[
      {n1 == E^(r (1 - n1 - 0.6 n2)) n1, n2 == E^(r (1 - 1.2 (0.6 n1 + n2))) n2}
    , {n1, n2}]
  ]
, {r, 1.0, 2.0, 0.1}]
```

gives

```
1. {{n1->1.,n2->0.},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583}}
1.1 NSolve[{n1==E^(1.1 (1-n1-0.6 n2)) n1,n2==E^(1.1 (1-1.2 (0.6 n1+n2))) n2},{n1,n2}]
1.2 {{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583}}
1.3 {{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583}}
1.4 {{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583}}
1.5 {{n1->1.,n2->0.},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583}}
1.6 {{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583}}
1.7 {{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583}}
1.8 {{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583}}
1.9 NSolve[{n1==E^(1.9 (1-n1-0.6 n2)) n1,n2==E^(1.9 (1-1.2 (0.6 n1+n2))) n2},{n1,n2}]
```

and hangs on `r=2.0` when I run it on Mathematica 10.4.1 on MacOS 10.11.6.  I tried all of the `NSolve` `Methods` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103029/6358) but they make no difference.

Bug? Possible workaround (not for this particular problem, but this phenomenon in general)?

Comment: I wouldn't really rely on it for solving transcendental equations.

Comment: Do you want real or complex solutions?

Comment: It's usually wise to eliminate extraneous variables and simplify equations anyway. Removing them solves the entire loop in a fraction of a second.

Comment: there are actually four solutions. Interesting it never finds the trivial {0,0}. If you specify `Reals` it finds all four in some cases but still hangs on others.

Comment: Yes, there should be four real solutions.  Solving this particular problem isn't the real issue, it's that I have a function that calls `NSolve` on unknown arguments that might fail.  Anyhow, I'll think about changing that function to not rely so heavily on `NSolve`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) the equations and use rational values of `r` (i.e., use exact numbers) and restrict the domain to nonnegative `Reals`. Although this is quite slow, it works.

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)

eqns = {
   n1 == E^(r (1 - n1 - 3/5 n2)) n1,
   n2 == E^(r (1 - 6/5 (3/5 n1 + n2))) n2,
   n1 >= 0, n2 >= 0};

Do[Print[r // N, " ",
  soln = NSolve[eqns, {n1, n2}, Reals],
  " ", And @@ (And @@ eqns /. soln)],
 {r, 1, 2, 1/10}]

(*  1. {{n1->0,n2->0},{n1->0,n2->0.833333},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583},{n1->1.,n2->0}} True

1.1 {{n1->0,n2->0},{n1->0,n2->0.833333},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583},{n1->1.,n2->0}} True

1.2 {{n1->0,n2->0},{n1->0,n2->0.833333},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583},{n1->1.,n2->0}} True

1.3 {{n1->0,n2->0},{n1->0,n2->0.833333},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583},{n1->1.,n2->0}} True

1.4 {{n1->0,n2->0},{n1->0,n2->0.833333},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583},{n1->1.,n2->0}} True

1.5 {{n1->0,n2->0},{n1->0,n2->0.833333},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583},{n1->1.,n2->0}} True

1.6 {{n1->0,n2->0},{n1->0,n2->0.833333},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583},{n1->1.,n2->0}} True

1.7 {{n1->0,n2->0},{n1->0,n2->0.833333},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583},{n1->1.,n2->0}} True

1.8 {{n1->0,n2->0},{n1->0,n2->0.833333},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583},{n1->1.,n2->0}} True

1.9 {{n1->0,n2->0},{n1->0,n2->0.833333},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583},{n1->1.,n2->0}} True

2. {{n1->0,n2->0},{n1->0,n2->0.833333},{n1->0.78125,n2->0.364583},{n1->1.,n2->0}} True  *)
```

Comment: Thanks!  In my quick testing, it's the `Reals` not the rational numbers that prevents the wrong and non-answers, which is for the better, because I can't insist on rational numbers in actual cases.  Still, some `r` values take 2 minutes while others take 0.1 seconds.

Comment: @ChrisK - you don't have to insist on rational numbers since you can `Rationalize` any equations: `eqns // Rationalize[#, 0] &`.  `NSolve` will do this sometimes; but when it does, it throws a waning: "NSolve::ratnz: NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result."