# NSolve gives an empty solution at some values

Tags: equation-solving

I have the equation

$$
x(\phi)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\left(\frac{-2}{\phi}+\log\left(\frac{1+\phi}{1-\phi}\right)\right)
$$
I need to find the dependence $\phi(x)$, so I use `NSolve`:

```
B = 20;
NSteps = 2*B*100; 
H = N[2*B/NSteps];
X = Range[-B, B, H];
F[i_] := NSolve[x[ϕ] == i && (-1.0 <= ϕ <= 0.0), ϕ];
Monitor[PhiTable = Table[ϕ /. F[i], {i, -B, B, H}], i]
```

And I get this output:

[image: Output]

`NSolve` can't find the solution and it gives an empty result at the values from about -15 and lower. I suppose this bug is caused by exponential asymptotic of the function $\phi(x)$.

But when I write

```
F[i_] := NSolve[x[ϕ] == i, ϕ, Reals];
Monitor[PhiTable = Table[ϕ /. F[i][[1]], {i, -B, B, H}], i]
```

It finds roots at the begining but freezes at the point 16.44 and higher.

Is there a way to fix it? Or shall I use another function, not `NSolve`?

**Added:**

```
x[ϕ_] := 1/(2 Sqrt[2]) (-2/ϕ + Log[(1 + ϕ)/(1 - ϕ)]);
```

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Could you give Mathematica code for your definition of `x[\[Phi]]`?  Could be similar to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/122027/nsolve-unreliable).

Comment: It looks like your equation $x(\phi) = x_0$ has two solutions for all values of $x_0$, one with positive $\phi$ and one with negative $\phi$.  Do you have a preference as to which one is returned?

Comment: @ChrisK definition: x[\[Phi]_] := 
  1/(2 Sqrt[2]) (-2/\[Phi] + Log[(1 + \[Phi])/(1 - \[Phi])]);
I also added it to the post as screenshot

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yes, I need negative one. Therefore I used the restrictions on phi in the first example

Comment: Sorry, I can't add the screenshot of the function x[\[Phi]] due to my reputation. But it has the same view as the equation at the begining of the question.

Comment: A side issue, unrelated to the problem: You should avoid starting your symbol names with a capital letter, especially single character variables.  Quite a few are reserved symbols used by *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root tracker `TrackRoot` I wrote [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104694/6358) can be applied to this problem.  First, run `TrackRoot` from that link.

[image]

Then:

```
x[ϕ_] := 1/(2 Sqrt[2]) (-2/ϕ + Log[(1 + ϕ)/(1 - ϕ)]);
tr = TrackRoot[{x[ϕ] - xval}, {ϕ}, {xval, -20, 20}, 0, {-0.5}];
Plot[ϕ[x] /. tr, {x, -20, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Is it possible to correct this function and  not to use interpolation? I'd like to get only values of phi. Sorry if it is a very foolish and simple question, I have never worked with manual functions before.

Comment: @Chertan I'm not sure if this is exactly what you mean by correcting this function, but you can extract particular values of `\[Phi]` like this: `\[Phi][1] /. tr` gives `-0.506903`.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I meant. Thank you!