# How to remove unnecessary answers from NSolve without losing speed?

Tags: equation-solving

This code:

```
eqs =
  {Ca/u^2 + 
      r (6 a (c^2 - d^2) + 12 b c d + 6 (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) Ca + 
         Ca^3) == 0,
    a (1/u^2 - 1) + 
      r (3 a (a^2 + b^2) + 6 a (c^2 + d^2) + 3 c^2 Ca - 3 d^2 Ca + 
         3 a Ca^2) == 1/2,
    b (1/u^2 - 1) + 
      r (3 b (a^2 + b^2) + 6 b (c^2 + d^2) + 6 c d Ca + 3 b Ca^2) == 0,
    c (1/u^2 - 1/4) + 
      r (6 (a^2 + b^2) c + 3 c (c^2 + d^2) + 6 (a c + b d) Ca + 
         3 c Ca^2) == 0,
    d (1/u^2 - 1/4) + 
      r (6 (a^2 + b^2) d + 3 d (c^2 + d^2) + 6 (-a d + b c) Ca + 
         3 d Ca^2) == 0, c > 0, d >= 0,
QQQ == c^2 + d^2, QQQ != 0
    } // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
NSolve[eqs /. {u -> 5, r -> 0.04}, {a, b, c, d, Ca, QQQ}, Reals]
```

Gives me this answer:

```
{{a -> -0.732167, b -> 0, c -> 1.06332, d -> 0, Ca -> 0.443594, 
  QQQ -> 1.13066}, 
 {a -> -0.732167, b -> 0, c -> 1.06332, d -> 0, 
  Ca -> 0.443594, QQQ -> 1.13066}, 
 {a -> -0.732167, b -> 0, 
  c -> 1.06332, d -> 0, Ca -> 0.443594, 
  QQQ -> 1.13066}, {a -> -0.732167, b -> 0, c -> 1.06332, d -> 0, 
  Ca -> 0.443594, QQQ -> 1.13066}, {a -> -0.698614, b -> 0, 
  c -> 0.622043, d -> 0.622043, Ca -> 0, 
  QQQ -> 0.773876}, {a -> -0.698614, b -> 0, c -> 0.622043, 
  d -> 0.622043, Ca -> 0, QQQ -> 0.773876}, {a -> -0.698614, b -> 0, 
  c -> 0.622043, d -> 0.622043, Ca -> 0, 
  QQQ -> 0.773876}, {a -> -0.698614, b -> 0, c -> 0.622043, 
  d -> 0.622043, Ca -> 0, QQQ -> 0.773876}, {a -> -0.698614, b -> 0, 
  c -> 0.622043, d -> 0.622043, Ca -> 0, 
  QQQ -> 0.773876}, {a -> -0.698614, b -> 0, c -> 0.622043, 
  d -> 0.622043, Ca -> 0, QQQ -> 0.773876}, {a -> -0.698614, b -> 0, 
  c -> 0.622043, d -> 0.622043, Ca -> 0, QQQ -> 0.773876}}
```

But as you see, there are several identical answers.
And if a make WorkingPrecision -> 3, for example, this code is slow down.
Maybe there is other methods to make this code faster?

Comment: "But as you see, there are several identical answers." - that's a sign that those are multiple roots, which might present special considerations. You are fortunate that `NSolve[]` is telling you this.

Comment: J.M. pointed out duplicate zeros, but if only a single solution was wanted, replace `NSolve` with `FindInstance`. But be aware that there are other solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eqs = {Ca/u^2 + 
     r (6 a (c^2 - d^2) + 12 b c d + 6 (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) Ca + Ca^3) == 
    0, a (1/u^2 - 1) + 
     r (3 a (a^2 + b^2) + 6 a (c^2 + d^2) + 3 c^2 Ca - 3 d^2 Ca + 3 a Ca^2) ==
     1/2, b (1/u^2 - 1) + 
     r (3 b (a^2 + b^2) + 6 b (c^2 + d^2) + 6 c d Ca + 3 b Ca^2) == 0, 
   c (1/u^2 - 1/4) + 
     r (6 (a^2 + b^2) c + 3 c (c^2 + d^2) + 6 (a c + b d) Ca + 3 c Ca^2) == 0,
    d (1/u^2 - 1/4) + 
     r (6 (a^2 + b^2) d + 3 d (c^2 + d^2) + 6 (-a d + b c) Ca + 3 d Ca^2) == 
    0, c > 0, d >= 0, QQQ == c^2 + d^2, QQQ != 0};
```

Note that since your equations are exact, there is no benefit to using [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html).

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) can rapidly find the exact real solutions and show that there are only two.

```
sol = Solve[eqs /. {u -> 5, r -> 1/25}, {a, b, c, d, Ca, QQQ}, Reals] // 
  RootReduce
```

[image]

Use [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) to convert the [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions to their approximate numeric values.

```
soln = sol /. x_Root :> N[x]

(* {{a -> -0.698614, b -> 0, c -> 0.622043, d -> 0.622043, Ca -> 0, 
  QQQ -> 0.773876}, {a -> -0.732167, b -> 0, c -> 1.06332, d -> 0, 
  Ca -> 0.443594, QQQ -> 1.13066}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Compare solutions with lower precision after `NSolve` is done:

```
NSolve[eqs /. {u -> 5, r -> 0.04}, {a, b, c, d, Ca, QQQ}, Reals] // 
 DeleteDuplicatesBy[SetPrecision[#, 6] &]
(*
{{a -> -0.732167, b -> 0, c -> 1.06332,
  d -> 0, Ca -> 0.443594, QQQ -> 1.13066},
 {a -> -0.698614, b -> 0, c -> 0.622043, 
  d -> 0.622043, Ca -> 0, QQQ -> 0.773876}}
*)
```

*Aside:* The following hardly seems an answer, but it gets the job done.  Set `Method` to something other than `Automatic` or `"Homotopy"`, even bogus settings, and `NSolve` returns solutions without multiplicities:

```
NSolve[eqs /. {u -> 5, r -> 0.04}, {a, b, c, d, Ca, QQQ}, Reals, 
 Method -> "Foo"]

(*
{{a -> -0.732167, b -> 0., c -> 1.06332,
  d -> 0., Ca -> 0.443594, QQQ -> 1.13066},
 {a -> -0.698614, b -> 0., c -> 0.622043, 
  d -> 0.622043, Ca -> 0., QQQ -> 0.773876}}
*)
```

Comment: Can you check if `Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix"` yields a solution without multiplicities?

Comment: @J.M. I checked [all the methods list here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103029/4999), including `"EndomorphismMatrix"`, plus a few others I made up.

Comment: I also considered these method suboptions ``Internal`NSolveOptions[]`` --> `{"ComplexEquationMethod" -> Automatic, "MonomialOrder" -> Automatic, 
 "ReorderVariables" -> True, "SelectCriterion" -> (True &), 
 "Tolerance" -> 0, "UseSlicingHyperplanes" -> True}`. Couldn't figure out how to get any them to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are sure that you can ignore the root multiplicities, then you can rationalize your results with an appropriately chosen rounding threshold, then use `DeleteDuplicates` to remove the multiple roots:

```
solns = NSolve[
          eqs /. {u -> 5, r -> 0.04}, 
          {a, b, c, d, Ca, QQQ}, 
          Reals
        ];

DeleteDuplicates@ Rationalize[solns, 0.0001] // N

(*Out:
{{a -> -0.732143, b -> 0., c -> 1.06329,
  d -> 0., Ca -> 0.443548, QQQ -> 1.13072},

 {a -> -0.69863, b->0., c -> 0.621951,
  d -> 0.621951, Ca -> 0., QQQ -> 0.77381}}
*)
```